# Adding dictonary with static keys inside another dictonary in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, overwrite

I wanna make a dictonary with another dictonary that have fixed keys e.g

```
dic1 = {'filename':'file1','namelen':'5'}
dic2 = {
"file1":dic1,
"file2":dic2,
...
...
}
```

The issue with my code is adding a new dictonary overwrites all the exisitng inner dictonary.

```
dic1 ={}
dic2 ={}
file_list = ["file1","file2", "file3"]
for file in file_list:
 dic1["filename"] = file
 dic1["namelen"] = len(file)
 dic2[file] = dic1
print(dic2)
```

My dictonary looks like this

```
    dic2 = 
{
'file1': {'namelen': 5, 'filename': 'file3'}, 
'file3': {'namelen': 5, 'filename': 'file3'}, 
'file2': {'namelen': 5, 'filename': 'file3'}
}
```

How to prevent the overwrite, without switching to list ?

Comment: Move `dic1 ={}` inside your `for loop`

Comment: `dic2` is not valid Python, as it is it represents a set with dictionaries (which are not hashable)

Comment: @DaniMesejo, I have corrected in the first description. Sorry for that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a copy of dictionary instead of the dictionary itself.

This line:

```
dic2[file] = dic1
```

changes to:

```
dic2[file] = dic1.copy()
```

Comment: yes this works ! thanks. So when doing dic2[file] = dic1 don't copy the data but only the reference of the object. What ever is the last value of dic1 will be there in dic2 for all embedded dictonaries !

Comment: Yeah, `dic2[file] = dic1` is adding reference (like, pointer). When the value pointing to that changes, all references are updated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
dic2 ={}
file_list = ["file1","file2", "file3"]
for f in file_list:
 dic1 ={}

 dic1["filename"] = f
 dic1["namelen"] = len(f)
 dic2[f] = dic1
print(dic2)
```

each and every iteration try creating a new `dict1={}` inside the loop

Otherwise,if you do outside the loop,it will reference the same dictionary again and again

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single line of python code in for to achieve your result.

```py
dic ={}
file_list = ["file1","file2", "file3"]
for file in file_list:
    dic[file] = { "filename": file, "namelen": len(file) }
print(dic)
```

#### Output

```
{
   'file1': {'filename': 'file1', 'namelen': 5}, 
   'file2': {'filename': 'file2', 'namelen': 5}, 
   'file3': {'filename': 'file3', 'namelen': 5}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might useful.

```
dic2 = dict()
file_list = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
for file_name in file_list:
    dic1 = dict()
    dic1["filename"] = file_name
    dic1["namelen"] = len(file_name)
    dic2[file_name] = dic1
print(dic2)
```

Output:

```
{
     'file1': {'filename': 'file1', 'namelen': 5},
     'file2': {'filename': 'file2', 'namelen': 5},
     'file3': {'filename': 'file3', 'namelen': 5}
}
```